# what are important features we consider to choose best online testing tool

Tags: automated-testing

I want to know what are the important features we have to consider to choose automation testing tool and what is the best open source online tool

Comment: I hope the following links may useful to you. http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/choosing-automation-tool-for-your-organization/ https://www.testing-whiz.com/blog/4-ways-to-select-the-right-software-test-automation-tool

Comment: define "best" :-)